# Dynamically create textbox based on amount of strings in array

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, web-services, textbox

I am iterating through an array of strings.

For each string I need it to be presented in a new textbox on the web page.

I have got this working by just having one textbox available, however this worked as a proof of concept. My problem being I am dealing with larger arrays now, with a varying amount of strings.

Is there a method to dynamically create textboxes on the page in relation to how many strings there are?

Here is what I have so far-

```
     protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        WebService1 ws = new WebService1();

        foreach (string x in ws.mRETURN(CheckBoxList1.SelectedItem.Text))
        {

            TextBox1.Text = x;

        }  
     }
```

So textbox one already exists on the page, however I know need it to be dependant on how many strings there are being passed from the webservice, and relate this number to the amount of textboxes needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Markup

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" ID="repeatedTextBox">
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:TextBox ID="myTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>'></asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Codebehind

```
repeatedTextBox.DataSource = myChangingArrayOfString;  //e.g ws.mRETURN(CheckBoxList1.SelectedItem.Text)
repeatedTextBox.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a placeholder on the webpage and adding controls(TextBoxes) to it programatically.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder id="Area1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder></P>
```

Then on your back end add:

```
TextBox tbx = new TextBox();
Area1.Controls.Add(tbx);
```

In a loop you could do that?
I am still learning so its my best suggestion at this stage.

Derived from source: [Source](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/3826/adding-controls-to-placeholders-dynamically/)